# How to migrate C# Application Settings from one app to another?

Tags: c#, application-settings, settings.settings

I have written a console application which I want to migrate to a Windows Service application.

I have written a lot of C# application settings which are in Scope Application.

I can see that the applications settings live in the Settings.Designer.cs file, in the

app.config file and possibly also other places.

I would like to avoid typing in all the application settings once again.

So my question is how to migrate the application settings from the console application to the

application settings in the Windows Service?

Comment: I found the solution to my answer on this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c4399664-44fe-4245-8ebd-111447479bfb

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my answer on this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c4399664-44fe-4245-8ebd-111447479bfb